# C pointer exercise

Tags: c, pointers

I am having problems with a c pointer exercise.
I understand how a pointer works but this exercise is confusing me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* c[] =

{
"he dast ga",
"lllt dumm",
"C i",
"dar nich"
};

char** cp[] = { c + 3, c + 2, c + 1, c };
char*** cpp = cp;

int main(void)

{
    printf("%s", **++cpp);
    printf("%s", *-- * ++cpp + 5);
    printf("%s", cpp[-2][0] + 2);
    printf("%s\n", *(cpp[1] + 1) + 3);
    getchar();
}
```

Could someone please explain this to me?

I thought that the pointer cpp would be incremented and point to the value c + 2. I coincidentally got the right result but it didn't work for the second pointer. Then I looked up that the ++ is not an increment but that the first value of the array gets cut of so that I have a new array with the values { c + 2, c + 1, c }. But I still don't know how I get "c i" as a result from this.

Comment: `*-- * ++cpp` - love it

Comment: Is this just exploring various flavours of undefined behaviour?

Comment: Tip: C is confusing enough as it is, don't make it worse on yourself. Use `c[n]` instead of `*(c + n)`.

Comment: Is this code you wrote or code your teacher gave you?

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso This is an exercise from my teacher

Comment: Which one are you stuck on? I'd recommend walking through each one and keeping track of where each variable is pointing, on paper

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso I don't understand this  *-- * ++cpp + 5

Comment: This exercise is, shall we say, questionable.  If you can understand it, then yes, you will certainly come to understand a lot about C and pointers.  Whether this sort of exercise is the best way to gain that understanding, though, is quite another question.  And, in any case, there's a second lesson that this exercise teaches: not just (a) pointers in C are powerful but can be tricky, but also (b) an expression like `*-- * ++cpp + 5` is an obvious abomination, and anyone who writes it should be shot, or at least have their programmer's license taken away. :-)

Comment: There's potentially a third lesson: (c) C programming is painful and about as much fun as hitting yourself in the face with a stick.  But please don't come away with this lesson.  C programming can be quite pleasant; it doesn't have to be this way.

Comment: Be relieved to know that if you came across nonsense like that in”real code”, you would get the culprit to rewrite it for better clarity.  That is purely an intellectual exercise, not symptomatic of the way code is written in production software.

Answer (score 2):

Let's keep track of where everything is pointing as we go through:

Initially, we have this:

```
c:   { "he dast ga", "lllt dumm", "C i", "dar nich" }
cp:  { c + 3, c + 2, c + 1, c }
cpp: cp
```

`printf("%s", **++cpp);` increments `cpp`, so we now have `cpp: cp + 1`.

Then, dereference it twice: `*cpp: c + 2`, `**cpp: "C i"`.

So we print out `C i`. And our variables now look like this:

```
c:   { "he dast ga", "lllt dumm", "C i", "dar nich" }
cp:  { c + 3, c + 2, c + 1, c }
cpp: cp + 1
```

Note that `cpp` has changed.

`printf("%s", *-- * ++cpp + 5);` is next.

First we increment `cpp` again: `cpp: cp + 2`. Then dereference it: `*cpp: c + 1`. Then decrement, giving us `c` and updating the appropriate element of `cp`. Then, dereference: `*c: "he dast ga"`, then add 5: `st ga`.

So we print out `st ga`, and our variables look as follows:

```
c:   { "he dast ga", "lllt dumm", "C i", "dar nich" }
cp:  { c + 3, c + 2, c, c }
cpp: cp + 2
```

Note the two updates, to `cp[2]` and `cpp`.

We don't update any more variables from this point on, so I will not show the variables anymore, just what happens as we evaluate.

`printf("%s", cpp[-2][0] + 2);`

```
cpp[-2][0] + 2
(cp + 2)[-2][0] + 2
cp[0][0] + 2
(c + 3)[0] + 2
c[3] + 2
"dar nich" + 2
"r nich"
```

So we print out `r nich`.

Finally, `printf("%s\n", *(cpp[1] + 1) + 3);`:

```
*(cpp[1] + 1) + 3
*(*(cpp + 1) + 1) + 3
*(*(cp + 2 + 1) + 1) + 3
*(*(cp + 3) + 1) + 3
*(c + 1) + 3
"lllt dumm" + 3
"t dumm"
```

So we print out `t dumm`.

Putting everything together, we should print out `C ist gar nicht dumm` (Roughly: "C is not so dumb after all" I believe).

Comment: A very nice explanation of an (in my opinion) very awful exercise.

Comment: @Lapiz I hope it helps, let me know if anything is unclear still